# php ldap search slow and failed, while ldapsearch command with same host, port and users works good

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I got this problem and have no idea to solve, can anyone give some suggestion? :)

The command line I use:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -h xxx -p xxx -x -D user01 -w aost.234 -b "DC=contoso,DC=com" "objectClass=*"
```

I can get result with command, but if I use the following php codes, I always got error with ldap_search function:

```
<?php

echo microtime(true).": start connect ldap server\r\n";
$ldapconn = ldap_connect('xxxx', xxx) or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");

ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

// ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
// ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 5);

echo microtime(true).": ldap server connected, start bind ldap session\r\n";

$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, 'user01', 'aost.234');

echo microtime(true).": ldap session binded, start search\r\n";

$result = ldap_search($ldapconn, "DC=contoso,DC=com", "objectClass=*");
if(!$result){
    die(microtime(true).": ldap search returns false\r\n");
}

echo microtime(true).": ldap search result found\r\n";

$info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

print_r($info);
?>
```

I tried to execute this php and get this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# php ldap_test.php 
1512703670.3936: start connect ldap server
1512703670.3943: ldap server connected, start bind ldap session
1512703670.4689: ldap session binded, start search
PHP Warning:  ldap_search(): Search: Can't contact LDAP server in /media/sf_www/ldap_test.php on line 18
1512704185.0035: ldap search returns false
```

Comment: Are you doing the connections on the same machine? Is the backend an AD or an OpenLDAP or something else? It seems that in PHP the connection to the LDAP server can‘t be established. So the issue actually happens on the ldap_bind, not on the ldap_search. What‘s the exact error message there? BTW have a look in the docs at how to correctly call ldap_connect.

Comment: @heiglandreas, thank you for the reply man, yes I'm doing the connections on the same machine, the backend is a AD, I tried to var_dump the return value of ldap_bind, its true, so I think ldap_bind have no problem, I have read the docs about ldap_connect and I assume my code is right, can you please tell me more? :)

Comment: When your backend is an AD I‘m not sure whether you need a secure connection to it via ldaps...

Comment: @heiglandreas, no need a secure connections, I use -x in the command also proved this :)

Comment: Have you tried dis- or enabling following referals? Like this: ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 1); (or 0 for disabling)...